# Take email from vk.com django-social-auth in Django

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I use django-social-auth in my Django project. I need to recieve e-mail from users. Facebook works fine with this in **settings.py**:

```
FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email']
FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
'fields': 'id, name, email',
}
```

Auth works fine and i recieve user's email address.
When i try to do the same with VK.com:

```
VK_EXTRA_SCOPE = ['email']
VK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
'fields': 'id, name, email',
}
```

Auth works fine, extra scope works fine, but i don't recieve e-mail. 
I also tried:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_VK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS
SOCIAL_AUTH_VK_EXTRA_DATA  
VK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS
VK_EXTRA_DATA
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Says here http://new.vk.com/dev/permissions email is only available for sites. Could that be it?

Comment: @LauriElias my app is site